# How to use TexMathZones in Markdown Syntax, for Snippets?

Tags: vimscript, filetype-tex, vimscript-python, plugin-ultisnips, filetype-markdown

I am a recent and very happy Vim User.
I write Mathematics and Computer Science Lecture Notes in Markdown Files, organized in a Vimwiki.
I use the UltiSnips Snippet Plugin.

This plugin provides me with the possibility of defining snippets which only expand in a `TexMathZone` ("UltiSnips-context-snippets").
This happens through a Python function (see [1] below) returning true if the cursor is in a `TexMathZone`. That means that snippet expands when within `$` or `$$` delimiters (`TexMathZoneX`, `TexMathZoneY`).

This works perfectly in `.tex` Files, but not in `.md` Files.
Setting the syntax to Tex by `:set syntax=tex` makes it work, but breaks markdown preview and syntax highlighting, which is unwanted.

I suspect this is because the syntax file for the markdown filetype does not define `TexMathZone`

How can I define or extend a markdown syntax file, such that the function in [1] delivers the same behaviour in markdown files as in Tex files? It should not inherit the other Tex syntax, and it should keep markdown syntax.

References:
[1] Minimal `markdown.snippets` file, as seen on [Gilles Castel's Snippet Configuration File](https://github.com/gillescastel/latex-snippets/blob/master/tex.snippets) :

```
global !p
texMathZones = ['texMathZone' + x for x in ['A', 'AS', 'B', 'BS', 'C', 'CS', 'D', 'DS', 'E', 'ES', 'F', 'FS', 'G', 'GS', 'H', 'HS', 'I', 'IS', 'J', 'JS', 'K', 'KS', 'L', 'LS', 'DS', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z', 'AmsA', 'AmsB', 'AmsC', 'AmsD', 'AmsE', 'AmsF', 'AmsG', 'AmsAS', 'AmsBS', 'AmsCS', 'AmsDS', 'AmsES', 'AmsFS', 'AmsGS' ]]
texIgnoreMathZones = ['texMathText']
texMathZoneIds = vim.eval('map('+str(texMathZones)+", 'hlID(v:val)')")
texIgnoreMathZoneIds = vim.eval('map('+str(texIgnoreMathZones)+", 'hlID(v:val)')")
ignore = texIgnoreMathZoneIds[0]
def math():
    synstackids = vim.eval("synstack(line('.'), col('.') - (col('.')>=2 ? 1 : 0))")
    try:
        first = next(i for i in reversed(synstackids) if i in texIgnoreMathZoneIds or i in texMathZoneIds)
        return first != ignore
    except StopIteration:
        return False
endglobal

context "math()"
snippet t "test" iAe
test!
endsnippet
```

Answer (score 1):

This works for markdown files with the vimwiki filetype. The only change needed is the addition `["VimwikiMath", "VimwikiEqIn"]` to `texMathZones`.

```
texMathZones = ['texMathZone' + x for x in ['A', 'AS', 'B', 'BS', 'C', 'CS',
'D', 'DS', 'E', 'ES', 'F', 'FS', 'G', 'GS', 'H', 'HS', 'I', 'IS', 'J', 'JS',
'K', 'KS', 'L', 'LS', 'DS', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z', 'AmsA', 'AmsB', 'AmsC',
'AmsD', 'AmsE', 'AmsF', 'AmsG', 'AmsAS', 'AmsBS', 'AmsCS', 'AmsDS', 'AmsES',
'AmsFS', 'AmsGS' ]] + ["VimwikiMath", "VimwikiEqIn"]
```

I found those by inspecting a file with this vimscript. It prints all the syntax tags at the cursor location.

```
for id in synstack(line('.'), line('.'))
   echo synIDattr(id, "name")
endfor
```

Note that text in equation mode escapes the math context. (`$$\text{Lorem} $$`)

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]!

Answer (score 0):

I use the following math() context definition in `vimwiki.snippet`.
This only works if your cursor is in a fully paired `$` math delimiter. But putting a fully paired `$` and letting the cursor be between them is handy when using a snippet.
This is a rather limited implementation, but it does the job for me.

```
def math():
    synstackids = vim.eval("synstack(line('.'), col('.') - (col('.')>=2 ? 1 : 0))") # I don't understand this but it works
    try:
        return vim.eval(f"synIDattr({synstackids[0]},'name')") ==  'textSnipTEX'
    except:
        return False
```